# How to clone a remote branch into a local repository that already existed?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to using Git, and let's say I have a repository in GitHub with 2 branches; the **master** branch and a branch called **foo**. Initially I cloned only the master branch using:

> git clone --single-branch --branch master <repository_link>

And when I run `git branch -a`, it accordingly showed me 2 branches, **master** and **remotes/origin/master**.

My question is, how can I now clone/add the **foo** branch into my local repository? So that when I rerun `git branch -a` it will show me 4 branches; the 2 masters, a **foo** branch and its **remotes/origin/foo**.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess that breanch has been created in the github repo? You need to fetch: `git fetch --all`. That _won't_ create a local `foo` branch. But it can be easily created with: `git checkout -b foo`.

Comment: try git pull and run git branch -a. it will show your new branch as well which you can checkout.

Answer (score 4):

you can fetch all branches with
`git fetch --all`
it will fetch all the remote branches ,
it won't make any change on your local machine,
if you want to make changes , you can do
`git pull branchname`
if you want to checkout a branch without merging it with your local branch, you can create a new branch on your local with the same branch name,
`git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname`

Answer (score 1):

Run `git pull` .

Now run `git branch -a`. It should show your new branch.

Checkout now using `git checkout foo`. Should create a local branch foo and checkout your foo branch there.